# как выводить логи ошибок PHP в формате JSON

Tags: php, docker, логирование, graylog

У меня возникла необходимость вывода лога ошибок PHP в формате JSON и дополнительно в лог передать домен и URL запроса для облегчения определения места возникновения ошибки и ее воспроизведения.

Как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP позволяет имплементировать Callback функцию для пользовательской обработки ошибок. Для регистрации обработчика нужно использовать функции:

1. [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) - для регистрации обработчика ошибок
2. [set_exception_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php) - для регистрации обработчика исключений

Я сделал класс `Handler` для имплементацию обработчиков:

```
<?php

final class Handler {
    public function handleError(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile, int $errline) : bool
    {
        $message = $this->createMessage($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
        $this->putMessage($message);

        return true;
    }

    public function handleException(Throwable $ex) : void
    {
        $message = $this->createMessage(-1, $ex->getMessage(), $ex->getFile(), $ex->getLine());
        $this->putMessage($message);
    }

    private function createMessage(int $errno, string $errstr, string $errfile, int $errline) : string
    {
        $object = new stdClass();
        $object->host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?? '';
        $object->request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?? '';
        $object->query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?? '';
        $object->request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ?? '';
        $object->errno = $errno;
        $object->file = $errfile;
        $object->line = $errline;
        $object->message = $errstr;
        $object->date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);

        try {
            $json = json_encode($object, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR | JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR) . PHP_EOL;
        } catch (JsonException $exception) {
            return '{}' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        return $json;
    }

    private function putMessage(string $message) : void
    {
        file_put_contents('php://stderr', $message);
    }
}
```

А для того, чтобы зарегистрировать обработчики как можно раньше я написал скрипт `register_handlers.php`:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . /handler.php;
$handler = new Handler();

set_error_handler([$handler, 'handleError']);
set_exception_handler([$handler, 'handleException']);
```

и подключил его в php.ini через директиву [auto_prepend_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

Лог пишется в stderr и т.к. PHP-FPM у меня в докер-контейнере, то лог ошибок попадает в лог контейнера php и его можно как посмотреть командой `docker logs` или направить куда угодно нативными средствами докера. Я для своих нужд отправляю лог в GrayLog.